# Can't connect my flutter project to firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, flutter-getx

I'm trying to connect my flutter desktop application to firebase, but when I try to run the main this happened.

> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

I tried to update all my **dependencies** and tried **flutter clean** but nothing happened

Here is my code

**The main class**

```
import 'package:demo_app_admin/view/loginView.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'Auth/binding.dart';

Future<void> main()  async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialBinding: Binding(),
      home: LoginView(),
    );
  }
}
```

**The LoginView class**

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:demo_app_admin/Auth/auth_view_model.dart';

class LoginView extends GetWidget<AuthViewModel> {

  final AuthViewModel controller = AuthViewModel();
}
```

**And here is my authViewModel class**

```
import 'package:firedart/auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class AuthViewModel extends GetxController {

  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

}
```

Comment: Firebase does not support windows Yet.

Comment: you can check this support windows and linux https://github.com/invertase/flutterfire_desktop

Comment: @shreebhagwat ok so I have an Android app and I'm using firebase with it.
the desktop app is for management side so if I didn't use firebase with my desktop app is there somehow  a way that I can update and get the data on firebase?

Comment: What you can do is create a Web App, Firebase Base support webs. And You can host that locally or on a server. This will let you manage it from anywhere and you can open it on any Platform.

Comment: @shreebhagwat I did that and I got this problem

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72941434/using-vpn-with-flutter-web

Comment: Hi, for anyone who is interested in the official flutterfire desktop. please upvote for the feature request in the link below. thanx!
https://firebase.uservoice.com/forums/948424-general/suggestions/46591750-desktop-windows-linux-macos-support-for-flutte